# ViewState equal null asp.net

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I have the next code.

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  bool isDelayWarning = proxy.MerchantPaySystemSetting_IsHoldPaymentsAllow(clientID, PaySystem.Type));
  ViewState.Add("IsDelayWarning", isDelayWarning);
}

protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if ((bool)ViewState["IsDelayWarning"] && !cbxDelayConfirm.Checked)
  {
    this.CustomErrorMessage = Yandex_Term_Error;
    return;
  }
}
```

In btnSend_Click method ViewState["IsDelayWarning"] = null.

How can I resolve this trouble?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Just been playing around with this and the only way I can make `ViewState[key]` in a click handler `null` is by disabling ViewState. Can you check ViewState is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the logic you're going for, but a button push happens during post-back, before the page is rendered. Put breakpoints in your two methods to see their relative order.

[image: You can see a diagram here]

Pay attention to the yellow marked items, control event processing is one of them and it happens strictly before `PreRender`.

Comment: maybe I missed something here, but according to the question wouldn't the order be: 1) Page_PreRender 2) Serve Page to Browser 3) btnSend_Click 4) Page_PreRender. But once the click handler fires it should still have the ViewState value set on PreRender.

Comment: In my example, first I render page and void Page_Prerender. Then I call click event handler and in this point my viewstate object is null

Comment: There's two distinct page lifecycles involved. Once you press your button on the client side, a whole new page lifecycle begins, going through `PreRender` then the event handler, just like in the picture. I mean you can downvote all you want, it won't change how ASP.NET is *documented* to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check for null reference by doing something like this

```
if (something != null)
code ------
```

or another way if you will sometimes have null is to use. For example if user address is null

```
if (thisuser.Address == null)
{
 thisuser.Address = new Address();
}
thisuser.Address = user.Address.City;
```